# Python/Django multidimensional array

Tags: django

Excuse me for the basic question but I come from a PHP background and made use of multidimensional arrays to transfer information around.

What is the best alternative in Python?

```
$person[1]['name'] = 'bob'
$person[1]['age'] = 27
$person[1]['email'] = 'aaa@aa.com'
```

What I'm trying to is prepare an array to send to a template, I need to get a list of persons and then calculate when their next meeting/visit should be. I then want to send an array to the template like:

```
Name   Last Meeting Date     Next Meeting Date
Bob    01/04/2012            01/05/2015
```

The Next meeting date is calculated based on many variables so I just want to prepare the array in the view and then pass it to the template.

Answer (score 1):

`person = [{'name':'bob', 'age':27, 'email':'aaa@aa.com'}, {...}, {...}]`

though if you use django, you might want to check the documentation and how models (user model for instance) work, cause you won't need to declare a list of dicts...

Answer (score 0):

In Python we have different kinds of data structures, you can't just append data like in the example you show. What you need in this specific case is a `list` (which is an equivalent of a 1-dimensional `array`) filled with `dict`s (just as an `array` of key-value pairs) where you can define your data:

```
people = [{"name": "Bob", "last_meeting": yesterday, "next_meeting": tomorrow}, {...}, ...]
```

Check this link for more info on data structures in python: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Though, @nnaelle is right, if you are using **django** and not just python, you should check out how the framework manages requests using `Forms`, `Models`, `Querysets`, `views` and all the useful stuff that powers Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/

That will for sure ease a lot of your work ;)

Good luck!